# From an array of objects, I want to pick a random object from the array and set one of that object's variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, p5.js

I have an array named `grid`. Stored in that array is an object, `cell`. I want to set one of cell's variables(`isBomb`) to true.

I know that this isn't quite how to do it, but here is my(nonfunctioning implementation).

When I try to run it, I get this error message: `Main, line 32:Cannot set property '288' of undefined` I assume that's because I formatted it wrong. Could anyone help?

```
    for(var i in grid){
        for(var j=0; j<bombAmount; j++){
    this.isBomb[floor(random(grid.length))]=true;
                                        }
```

This is in javascript, with the p5.js library.

[Openprocessing link](https://openprocessing.org/sketch/961181)

Comment: You don't need a for loop for this, you just need to pick a random index. `grid[floor(random(grid.length))].isBomb = true;` To set a bunch of fields, you need to run this line inside your `j` loop, however you also need to pick a new random index if the field is already a bomb. You can use a while loop for that.

Comment: I think that worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math.random()` to achieve this. For example:

```js
const grid = [{
  cellId: 1
}, {
  cellId: 2
}, {
  cellId: 3
}, {
  cellId: 4
}, {
  cellId: 5
}, {
  cellId: 6
}, {
  cellId: 7
}, {
  cellId: 8
}, {
  cellId: 9
}, {
  cellId: 10
}];

function pickRandomCell() {
  return grid[Math.floor(Math.random() * grid.length)];
}

for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  console.dir(pickRandomCell());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the answer above, do **Math.random()** and update the cell like this:

```js
// Do a loop to apply each bomb to a cell
for (let i = 0; i < bombAmount; i++) {
    const randomPosition = Math.round(Math.random() * (grid.length -1));
    
    // Select random cell from grid, and update the "isBomb" to true
    grid[randomPosition].isBomb = true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few issues with the code that this question doesn't address.

I will start with the simplest question from the title: picking a random object from the an array. The existings answers already address this. I wanted to point out that [`random()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/random) in p5 can also take an array as an argument and returns a random item from that array, as you can see in the reference example:

```js
function setup(){
  let words = ['apple', 'bear', 'cat', 'dog'];
  let word = random(words); // select random word
  console.log(word);
  
  createCanvas(100, 100);
  text(word, 10, 50);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Back to the snippet you posted:

```
for(var i in grid){
  for(var j=0; j<bombAmount; j++){
    this.isBomb[floor(random(grid.length))]=true;
  }
}
```

In the context above `this` will not point to an individual cell.
You might be looking at something like `grid[i].isBomb = true` instead.

`isBomb` is a boolean property of `Cell` hence the errors when trying to access it via array access notation.

The connection between `bombAmount` and `isBomb` is unclear.
Perhaps you meant to use something like the `bombsFound` array returned by `checkArea()` somehow ?

If you want to pick a random cell to have a bomb or not you could something like:

```
for(let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++){
  grid[i].isBomb = random(0.0, 1.0) > 0.5;
}
```

the example above sets a psuedo random chance of 50/50 that a cell will be a bomb or not.

The `Cell` constructor actually accepts `isBomb` as it's last argument:

```
function Cell(x, y, bombNum, clicked, isBomb)
```

Therefore you could skip the loop completely and simply randomly assign `isBomb` when populating `grid`:

```
for (var y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < cols; x++) {

        
            var cell = new Cell(x, y, index(x, y), false, random(0.0, 1.0) > 0.5);
            
            grid.push(cell);
        }
    }
```

Currently it looks like you're not passing the expected arguments to the `Cell` constructor:

```
var cell = new Cell(x, y, false);
```

These are just a few of the issues and points out that you may not fully understand the code you're trying to modify. I recommend slowing down, stepping back for a second and with pen an paper figure out what you're trying to achieve. With the clear goals, break them down into very simple individual steps, solve one step at a time, then start integrating the tested individual steps into the larger program.

**Update** based on the clarification in the comment bellow you could easily do something like:

```
for(let i = 0; i < bombAmount; i++){
  grid[i].isBomb = random(0.0, 1.0) > 0.5;
}
```

However this won't guarantee 20 bombs, but a 50-50 chance that the 1st 20 cells might have bombs.

If you want to guarantee 20 bombs at random locations you could use a temporary array to pick a random from, but remove that randomly selected item so it won't be selected on the next iteration.

Here's a snippet to illustrate the idea:

```
// make a new array that will hold references to the original cells
let selection = grid.map(cell => cell);
// for the bomb amount...
for(let i = 0 ; i < bombAmount; i++){
  // pick a random index
  let randomIndex = floor(random(selection.length));
  // retrieve the cell at that index and remove it from the selection list
  let cell = selection.splice(randomIndex, 1);
  // set that cell as a bomb
  cell.isBomb = true
}
```

Comment: Hey, just to clarify, some stuff, bombAmount is a global variable that sets how many bombs will be generated(making minesweeper), And I wanted to avoid using a statement like that so it's more clear how many bombs I have, but this has been helpful, thank you!